# Add timestamp as variable sent in webform

Tags: javascript, webforms, timestamp

If I have a simple webform, like below, is there ANY way to take the output of the time function "now" and submit it as a webform variable ?
I've actually fixed it below, THANKS to Teemu.
What I want is to prevent the same form submission to happen more than once, either by refresh or the back button. The python script records the random string, Rand, sent in the hidden field, and if the python script sees it again, tells the user, 'already executed, hit the back button or close'

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Enter stuff and submit the form:</p>

<form id="frm1" action="cgi-bin/action_page.py">
 name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
 <input type="hidden" name="Rand">
 <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var d = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
 document.querySelector('[name="Rand"]').value = d;
  function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
  }
```

Comment: Add the timestamp to a hidden field on the form.

Comment: I am not sure how to set value equal to the timestamp. This would just put the word now in the form.
    <input type="hidden" name="time" value="now">

Comment: After adding that input element to the form, `document.querySelector('[name="time"]').value = d.getTime();` in the script does the trick.

Comment: I don't know how to click to thank you, but thank you.